# How to create new dataset based on existing dataset

Tags: r, criteria, rules

I have the following dataset:

```
individual    sequence_special_drug     all_drugs
A             NA                        A
A             NA                        B
A             1                         C
A             2                         D
A             NA                        B
A             NA                        Z
A             2                         D
A             NA                        Z
A             2                         D
A             NA                        A
A             3                         E
```

I would like to create the following dataset in R:

```
Individual  sequence_special_drug  special_drug  prior_special_drug  prior_traditional_drug   during_special_drug
A           1                      C             none                A, B                     none
A           2                      D             C                   none                     B, Z, Z
A           3                      E             C, D                A, B, B, Z, Z, A         none
```

Is there a quick way to do this? I have many individuals, but these are all the possible scenarios. A `special_drug` is identified by the sequence number; those with 'NA' are a `traditional_drug`.

`prior_special_drug` will contain any special_drug previously identified, so for the first special_drug C there is no previous special_drug, for the second special_drug D, there is one previous special_drug that is C, and for the third special_drug there are two previous special_drugs C and D.

`prior_traditional_drug` is the same but will contain anything that has been identified in sequence_special_drug as NA. So for the first special_drug (C), the two prior_traditional_drugs are A and B. For the third special_drug, the prior_traditional_drugs are A, B, B, Z, Z, A.

`during_special_drug` will contain every traditional_drug that have been referenced during the administration of special_drug. This can be identified in the dataset through the repetition of sequence_special_drug (e.g. 2 -> NA NA -> 2 -> NA -> 2) therefore B, Z, Z.

**EDIT** - For 2 individuals:

```
dat <- read.table(
  text = "
  individual    sequence_special_drug     all_drugs
A             NA                        A
A             NA                        B
A             1                         C
A             2                         D
A             NA                        B
A             NA                        Z
A             2                         D
A             NA                        Z
A             2                         D
A             NA                        A
A             3                         E
B             1                         D
B             NA                        B
B             NA                        Z
B             1                         D
B             NA                        Z
B             1                         D
B             NA                        A
B             2                         E",
  header = TRUE)
```

I would expect:

**- WRONG "none" line 3 under prior_traditional_drug -**

```
Individual  sequence_special_drug  special_drug  prior_special_drug  prior_traditional_drug   during_special_drug
A           1                      C             none                A, B                     none
A           2                      D             C                   none                     B, Z, Z
A           3                      E             C, D                A, B, B, Z, Z, A         none
B           1                      D             none                none                     B, Z, Z
B           2                      E             D                   B, Z, Z, A               none
```

**- RIGHT "A, B" line 3 under prior_traditional_drug -**

```
Individual  sequence_special_drug  special_drug  prior_special_drug  prior_traditional_drug   during_special_drug
A           1                      C             none                A, B                     none
A           2                      D             C                   A, B                     B, Z, Z
A           3                      E             C, D                A, B, B, Z, Z, A         none
B           1                      D             none                none                     B, Z, Z
B           2                      E             D                   B, Z, Z, A               none
```

But I obtained:
[image]

**Error message with my own dataset**

```
> special_drug <- example_data %>% 
+   nest_by(individual) %>% 
+   mutate(
+     spec_drug = list(get_all_drugs(data))
+   ) %>% 
+   unnest(spec_drug) %>%
+   select(-data) %>% 
+   ungroup()
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'sequence_special_drug'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
 Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `spec_drug`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `flag3`.
x `false` must be a list, not a character vector.
ℹ Input `flag3` is `if_else(flag1 == 1, list(character(0)), flag3)`.
ℹ Input `spec_drug` is `list(get_all_drugs(data))`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

 > rlang::last_error()
Error in is_rlang_error(parent) : 
  argument "parent" is missing, with no default
```

**My own dataset is more like this:**

```
example_data <- read.table(
  text = "
  individual    sequence_special_drug     all_drugs
77779             NA                      Name1
77779             1                       Name2
77779             1                       Name2
77779             1                       Name2
77779             2                       Name3
4444              NA                      Name1
4444              1                       Name4
4444              2                       Name3
4444              3                       Name7",
  header = TRUE)
```

But the dataset below also generates the same error message:

```
example_data <- read.table(
  text = "
  individual    sequence_special_drug     all_drugs
A               NA                        A
A               1                         C
A               2                         D
A               2                         D
A               2                         D
A               3                         E
B               NA                        B
B               1                         D
B               2                         E
B               3                         F",
  header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain how to create `prior_special_drug, prior_traditional_drug,during_special_drug`.

Comment: Thanks Peace Wang and apologies for not having it there in the first place - I've edited my question to include that information. Do you have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion using `{tidyverse}`. I wrote a function to get each column and then put them together in `get_all_drugs()`. Then, I ran the function through the nested data by individual, as in the example below.

```
library(tidyverse)

example_data <- read.table(
  text = "
  individual    sequence_special_drug     all_drugs
A             NA                        A
A             NA                        B
A             1                         C
A             2                         D
A             NA                        B
A             NA                        Z
A             2                         D
A             NA                        Z
A             2                         D
A             NA                        A
A             3                         E
B             1                         D
B             NA                        B
B             NA                        Z
B             1                         D
B             NA                        Z
B             1                         D
B             NA                        A
B             2                         E",
header = TRUE)
 
get_special_drugs <- function(.data) {
  .data %>% 
    filter(sequence_special_drug != 0) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    select(sequence_special_drug, special_drug = all_drugs) %>% 
    mutate(prior_special_drug = as.list(accumulate(special_drug, c))) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(prior_special_drug = list(
      prior_special_drug[prior_special_drug != special_drug]
    )) %>% 
    ungroup()
}

fix_drug_sequence <- function(.data) {
  .data %>% 
    mutate(
      seq_drug = replace_na(sequence_special_drug, 0),
      flag = if_else(seq_drug == 0 & seq_drug != lead(seq_drug),
                     lead(seq_drug),
                     seq_drug),
      flag = if_else(flag == 0 & flag != lead(flag),
                     lead(flag),
                     flag)
    ) %>% 
    select(-sequence_special_drug) %>% 
    rename(sequence_special_drug = flag)
}

get_prior_traditional_drug <- function(...) {
  fix_drug_sequence(...) %>% 
    group_by(sequence_special_drug) %>% 
    mutate(
      flag1 = max(seq_drug == sequence_special_drug & row_number() == 1),
    ) %>% 
    group_by(sequence_special_drug, flag1) %>% 
    summarise(
      flag2 = list(all_drugs[seq_drug == 0])
    ) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(
      flag3 = as.list(accumulate(flag2, append)),
      flag3 = if_else(flag1 == 1, lag(flag3), flag3)
    ) %>% 
    select(sequence_special_drug, prior_traditional_drug = flag3)
}

get_during_special_drugs <- function(...) {
  fix_drug_sequence(...) %>% 
    group_by(sequence_special_drug) %>% 
    mutate(
      flag = cumsum(seq_drug == sequence_special_drug)
    ) %>% 
    filter(flag > 0) %>% 
    summarise(
      during_special_drug = list(all_drugs[seq_drug == 0])
    )
}

get_all_drugs <- function(.data) {
  spec_drug <- get_special_drugs(.data)
  prior_traditional <- get_prior_traditional_drug(.data)
  during_spec <- get_during_special_drugs(.data)
  
  list(spec_drug, prior_traditional, during_spec) %>% 
    reduce(left_join, by = "sequence_special_drug")
}

special_drug <- example_data %>% 
  nest_by(individual) %>% 
  mutate(
    spec_drug = list(get_all_drugs(data))
  ) %>% 
  unnest(spec_drug) %>%
  select(-data) %>% 
  ungroup()

special_drug
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Zaw for your proposed solution. It is a general approach so that's really great. But it is still not working 100% yet (prior_special_drug, prior_traditional_drug and during_special_drug including drugs that should not be there). I am still trying to understand your logic and will get back to you on this.

Comment: Thanks again Zaw - your code does not seem to be grouping by individual. I've edited my question to include 2 individuals (A,B) - if you run that table, you will see that results are not correct. Do you have any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: Indeed Daniela. The code was only for one individual. To scale it over many individuals, one approach is to transform the code to a function and apply it to the dataset nested by individual. I have edited the example accordingly. Hope this helps.

Comment: I broke the big function into smaller ones for clarity and better debugging. I didn't get the same prior traditional drug for individual B, sequence special drug 2 though. The pattern in your expected results does not seem to be consistent with the individual A. I might be missing something.

Comment: Many thanks Zaw - you're right, your output is the correct one, I've edited my "expected results". When I run the example_data it works well, but with my own dataset (variables with same class), I get the error message above, any ideas?

Comment: Not sure - the problem probably is this step: `flag3 = if_else(flag1 == 1, list(character(0)), flag3)`. Both values to use for TRUE and FALSE in `if_else()` should be a list but `flag3` created in the previous row appears to be a character, rather than a list.

Comment: Thanks Zaw. I do not know where this flag3 is coming from. This error might be related to how I am setting up my dataset. I have included that in my question above, could you see any problems there? should it be a data.table or data.frame?

Comment: `flag3` is from this function: `get_prior_traditional_drug()`. You can perhaps try running it separately and step-by-step using a small chunk of your real data?

Comment: Many thanks Zaw. It seems that the code does not work with other datasets (with different sequences of drugs). I've included 2 examples above in my question. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I've found the problem. The output of `accumulate()` is not type stable - it is not always a list, as reported here (https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/809). So, I wrapped both calls of `accumulate()` with `as.list()`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zaw - it is working now. I just noticed I reported something wrong in my first table above for 2 individuals. I've edited it now (included both WRONG and RIGHT tables). Would your routine be able to accommodate for this last point? prior_traditional_drug needs to bring back everything prior, similar to prior_special_drug

Comment: I made some changes to `get_prior_traditional_drug()`. That should give the values you needed.

Comment: Thanks very much Zaw

Answer (score 1):

Here is my inelegant solution only for this specific problem, but it maybe useful to give you a hint.

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(
    "
individual    sequence_special_drug     all_drugs
A             NA                        A
A             NA                        B
A             1                         C
A             2                         D
A             NA                        B
A             NA                        Z
A             2                         D
A             NA                        Z
A             2                         D
A             NA                        A
A             3                         E
            "
)

df <- unique(na.omit(dt))
setnames(df,"all_drugs","special_drug")
df
#>    individual sequence_special_drug special_drug
#> 1:          A                     1            C
#> 2:          A                     2            D
#> 3:          A                     3            E

## add row ideantifier in dt
dt[,rd:=rowid(individual)]

## create prior_special_drug
df[,prior_special_drug:=shift(special_drug)]
df[3,4] <- df[special_drug < "E", paste(special_drug,collapse = ", ")]
df
#>    individual sequence_special_drug special_drug prior_special_drug
#> 1:          A                     1            C               <NA>
#> 2:          A                     2            D                  C
#> 3:          A                     3            E               C, D

special.drug = df$special_drug
special.drug
#> [1] "C" "D" "E"
posi <- c(
    dt[,first(.I[all_drugs==special.drug[1]])], #first position of C
    dt[,first(.I[all_drugs==special.drug[2]])], #first position of D
    dt[,last(.I[all_drugs==special.drug[2]])],  #last position of D
    dt[,last(.I[all_drugs==special.drug[3]])]   #last position of E
)
posi
#> [1]  3  4  9 11

# dt[is.na(sequence_special_drug) & rd < posi[1], all_drugs]
# dt[is.na(sequence_special_drug) & rd %between% posi[2:3], all_drugs]
# dt[is.na(sequence_special_drug) & rd < posi[4], all_drugs]

drug <- c(
    paste(dt[is.na(sequence_special_drug) & rd < posi[1], all_drugs],collapse = ", "),
    paste(dt[is.na(sequence_special_drug) & rd %between% posi[2:3], all_drugs],collapse = ", "),
    paste(dt[is.na(sequence_special_drug) & rd < posi[4], all_drugs],collapse = ", ")
)
drug
#> [1] "A, B"             "B, Z, Z"          "A, B, B, Z, Z, A"
## create prior_traditional_drug  and  during_special_drug
df[,prior_traditional_drug := drug]
df[,prior_traditional_drug := ifelse(special_drug == "D",NA,prior_traditional_drug)]

df[,during_special_drug := drug]
df[,during_special_drug := ifelse(special_drug %in% c("C","E"),NA,during_special_drug)]

## replace NA with "none" in df
for (jj in 1:ncol(df))
    set(df,
        i = which(is.na(df[[jj]])),
        j = jj,
        v = "none"
    )
df
#>    individual sequence_special_drug special_drug prior_special_drug
#> 1:          A                     1            C               none
#> 2:          A                     2            D                  C
#> 3:          A                     3            E               C, D
#>    prior_traditional_drug during_special_drug
#> 1:                   A, B                none
#> 2:                   none             B, Z, Z
#> 3:       A, B, B, Z, Z, A                none
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much Peace Wang - this works for this particular case displayed in my question, but this was just an example. For each individual in my dataset, there are other drugs which are displayed in different order, so this solution unfortunately does not apply to them.